podman and debian debootstrap on macos
I have the following problem when I run debootstrap in podman containers on macos.
debootstrap --arch=arm64 --foreign bookworm build
mknod: /root/pcmonitor-dev/build/test-dev-null: Operation not permitted
E: Cannot install into target '/root/pcmonitor-dev/build' mounted with noexec or nodev

The podman container is privileged.
I understand that podman only mounts the rootfs with noexec and nodev on macos. The strange thing is that I don't have this issue when I run podman and debootstrap in Debian 12 or Oracle Linux 8. Help is very much appreciated.
I would like to build debian images in podman on macos. This is my aim

After many trial and errors, I found a solution that is a bit strange.
The above bug only happens if the podman machine isn't the default one. That means if the machine is default (podman-machine-default) and rootful is set to true, this error doesnt occur but if the machine is named anything else like "podman-machine-fw", then this error occurs.
